# How to create a facebook like tickr?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am working on GPS tracking web application which shows information on various features like position,speed, heading towards and the image files recieved from his Mobile device. To make it more interactive I want to create a page called timeline which can show the updates in a auto-refreshing div like
1) USer-1 just uploaded a video
2) user2 has reached Texas at 12:00:34.
etc...

How can i make it.. i am not asking for code. Just want some verbal help and a little guidance.
Also i searched for the same on internet, but all the examples are in php and what i need is an example or reference in ASP.net. Please Help.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build an html5 phonegap app, you have a function called getcurrentlocation which can give you the latitude+longitute data and also the speed etc.. try to save this data or post it somewhere an then use this data on the web app. After that u can use google api to convert this geo data in to actual address data(reverse geocoding).

And in your asp.net page make use of UpdatePanels here you can put your "live" data, with this updatepanel control u can use a timed interval which refreshes the panel for example for 2 seconds, so you can check if there is new data every 2 seconds if yes update the updatepanel(ie insert new row with data on page, inside updatepanel). On this website you see a simple tutorial on how to do it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295400.aspx

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you BDZ for this reply... But i already have all this information. I have a phone app that is installed on the phone itself and sends the data on my server and fills into respective fields of the database.. What i am interested in is the designing part of the webpage. I mean the jquery,javascript and ajax part. I have every possible information saved in my database.